# how to launch my application in iphone?

Tags: iphone

I have build one of my application on iphone but refuse to build that on m iphone .

Can u tell me the proper steps for launching my application on my iphone and step by step procedure for setting the project settings.

Comment: You should review the Apple documentation -- they are pretty clear when it comes to the base development.

Answer (score 0):

This is the best tutorial on Apple's site:

http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhone101/Articles/00_Introduction.html

BTW, your question seems too much like "Teach me iPhone app development" which is a bit much to expect.